# Will pgAdmin III let me run an SQL command that works after detaching from my SSH tunnel?

Tags: pgadmin

I just discovered pgAdmin III and I am absolutely overwhelmed by the number of options it offers. I'd like to try to replace my traditional workflow (`psql` ran over an SSH session) with this tool. The problem is that I usually work on a hundred-million-row database and some of the queries I run hours or even days to complete. During that time, I'd like to be able to turn my client PC off. Does pgAdmin III support this workflow?

Comment: Related question: [Is a Postgres long-running query aborted if the connection is lost/broken?](http://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/81408/is-a-postgres-long-running-query-aborted-if-the-connection-is-lost-broken)

Comment: Have you ever figured a way around this? I'm thinking of using pgagent and storing the result of these long queries in "temporary" tables.

Comment: @MauricioScheffer: nope, I hadn't. I decided to use GNU Screen instead of pgadmin for this one.