# Could a query be still active after pgAdmin4 crashed?

Tags: postgresql, pgadmin-4

As i am asking in the title, I am wondering if a query can be still active after pgAdmin4 crashed ?

Indeed I was running a very long-time query..

```
CREATE TABLE intersection as ( 
SELECT buff.rownum as buffrownum,
       ST_Intersection(union.st_union, buff.st_buffer) AS geom 
FROM union, buff 
WHERE ST_Intersects (union.st_union, buff.st_buffer));
```

..when pgAdmin crashed... (due to my mistake I believe, as I runned a query in parallel to create a big table setting many rows...)

I have seen this [post](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/81408/is-a-postgres-long-running-query-aborted-if-the-connection-is-lost-broken) but as I am a very new user of PostgreSQL/postGIS, I didn't really understood the answer...

I opened again pgAdmin4 and did the query..

```
SELECT * FROM pg_stat_activity;
```

..and it returns me : 
[image]

As you can see the query in question (CREATE...) on the second line has still an "active" state. Does it mean that the query is still active even after pgAdmin4 closed ? I mean will the table "intersection" be created ?

Comment: Yes, that's possible because pgAdmin4 runs async queries.